# Asserting that an input element contains a specific value in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to assert the following where `propSizeSel` is the CSS selector to my numerical input element:

```
cy.get(propSizeSel).clear().type(100)
    .should('contain', 100);
```

Unfortunately, this assertion fails in the following manner despite the input element accepting the value of 100.

[image]

As you can see the input element has accepted the value 100 as expected:

[image]

**Why is it that I can't seem to make this simple assertion?**

Comment: contain is for text, `.should('have.value', 100)` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Please try with 100 in single quotes and in the assert, please use `should('have.value', '100')` instead of contain;

```
cy.get('propSizeSel').clear().type('100').should('have.value', '100');
```

or try asserting using a `promise`

```
cy.get('propSizeSel').clear().type('100').invoke('val')
    .then(val=>{    
      const myVal = val;      
      expect(myVal).to.equal('100');
    })
```

Answer (score 5):

As for 2022 there is a variety of approaches Cypress offers to assert a number input value, an entire string match, a substring, a regex or make a more complex custom assertions. Here is how.

```js
// Assume we have an input with `.my-input-class` class and the value `My input value` 
// in the markup.

// Then we find it (NB: do not forget getting the single one here e.g. with `.first()`
// as there can be many of the selected elements returned by `cy.get()`)
cy.get('.my-input-class).first()
    // This gets the input value for further assertions
    .invoke('val')
    // This would succeed if we had a number input with value `100`
    .should('have.value', 100)
    // Again for number
    .should('be.equal', 100)
    // And again, now with "greater then or equal" assertion
    .should('be.at.least', 100)
    // Now for strings, this matches the entire string
    .should('contain', 'My input value')
    // This matches the substring
    .should('include', 'My input')
    // Another substring match
    .should('have.string', 'My input')
    // Regex is here
    .should('match', /My/)
    // Here you can make any complex custom assertions JavaScript allows
    .then(($valueString)=>{
        console.log($valueString)
        if (!$valueString.includes('My')) {
            throw new Error('My custom assertion fails the test')
        }
    })
```

There are many string assertions you can make via Cypress, within `should` family or beyond. See the official [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions#Chai-jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

With @soccerway answer and some changes I found a way to achieve what I want since I was unable to properly compare floats, indeed, if the field have for instance 1.320 and I want to check value is 1.32, with @soccerway answer using string I will have something like `expected value to be '1.32' but got '1.320'` error, I then have done:

```
    cy.get('propSizeSel')
      .invoke('val')
      .then(val => {
        if (val !== undefined) {
          expect(parseFloat(val.toString())).to.equal(1.32);
        } else {
          expect(val).not.equal(undefined);
        }
      });
```

In the case of this question `parseInt` can be used instead of `parseFloat`, and to go further, since I have several calls like this to do, I made a `cypressCommonCommands.ts` file that contains two function to do this:

```
export class CypressCommonCommands {
  public static expectElementValueEqualsFloat(pCyElement: string, pValue: number) {
    cy.get(pCyElement)
      .invoke('val')
      .then(val => {
        if (val !== undefined) {
          expect(parseFloat(val.toString())).to.equal(pValue);
        } else {
          expect(val).not.equal(undefined);
        }
      });
  }

  public static expectElementValueEqualsInt(pCyElement: string, pValue: number) {
    cy.get(pCyElement)
      .invoke('val')
      .then(val => {
        if (val !== undefined) {
          expect(parseInt(val.toString())).to.equal(pValue);
        } else {
          expect(val).not.equal(undefined);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Then use for this question:

```
cy.get('propSizeSel').clear().type('100');
CypressCommonCommands.expectElementValueEqualsInt('propSizeSel', 100);
```